# How to install latest LTS Node in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded source code(.tar file) file from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

How i install node by tar file in my system?

Comment: You should use the commands provided there : https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Please don't add [SOLVED] to the question. Accepting an answer marks your question as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**

we can use this command to extract .tar file and install node in our system

1. In terminal go into directory where you download the tar file
2. Run command `tar -xf node-v8.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1`

And

We can download direct with this command

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -xf node-v8.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1
```

Check is node installed

```
node -v
npm -v
```

**Note**: If you getting permission issue then use `sudo` before command.