# Unable to install angular and node in ubuntu 16 system

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried different option to install node latest version in ubuntu 16, it was always taking node 4,

I have followed [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957439/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-on-ubuntu-server)

and now node -v gives me 8.X  than I have installed npm after that I am trying to install angular, its breaking error is in screen shot attachment 
I know it required npm 5.5.1 but how do I install that, I have used command

> npm install -g npm@latest

,
[image]

when I run command ng new myapp1 it gives error

> This command can not be run inside of a CLI project.

it didn't work finally, what can I do next

Comment: Try to install using [angular/cli](https://cli.angular.io/)

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406485/how-to-install-latest-lts-node-in-ubuntu-16-04/52418697#52418697) for install node

Comment: Thanks a lot It got installed but now I am stuck with angular issue "This command can not be run inside of a CLI project , even i have created a fresh new folder and run command in first link you have provided

Comment: try to install with sudo. because may be you have installed angular or node with sudo. so your directory not have permission to generate new file there.

Answer (score 0):

Use These command for Install Angular Cli & Create Angular Project

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

And if you want to install latest Node [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406485/how-to-install-latest-lts-node-in-ubuntu-16-04/52418697#52418697)

**Note** Use Sudo before NPM commands if you not have directory permissions.